# How to compare seconds at mysql

Tags: mysql, date, format

I'm Writing Mysql Query's

I am currently comparing dates using the between function.

```
UPDATE TOTAL2  

SET CHARGE = 'O'

WHERE STARTDAY BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2020-02-27 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AND DATE_FORMAT('2020-03-31 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')

AND ENDDAY IS NULL;
```

I wrote the update query above, but due to a coincidence, the value of the STARTDAY column included '2020-02-27 00:00:00', so the corresponding row was not reflected.

How do I modify the query to include that part as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can get desired result:

```
 UPDATE
  TOTAL2
SET
  CHARGE = 'O'
WHERE
  STARTDAY BETWEEN '2020-02-27 00:00:00'
  AND '2020-03-31 00:00:00'
  AND ENDDAY IS NULL;
```

Comment: Can't you use Between? For example, you need to compare hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: then just remove the DATE_FORMAT function, it will work.

E.g.: WHERE STARTDAY BETWEEN '2020-02-27 00:00:00' AND '2020-03-31 00:00:00'